# Could memory exceptions cause NullPointerException?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, out-of-memory

My android app is a little bit complicated and it has 34 activities, sometimes 5 of them stay on the background with a lot of bitmaps on them.

On new devices like galaxy s3  I never get an error. But on old devices with low memory I got a lot of NullPointerExceptions and not even one OutOfMemoryException.

So my question is: Could those NullPointerExceptions be caused by an OutOfMemoryException ???

This is one of the exceptions:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nasseralsalmi.wheel/com.nasseralsalmi.wheel.ModelsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException : at com.nasseralsalmi.wheel.ModelsActivity.onCreate(ModelsActivity.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.nasseralsalmi.wheel.ModelsActivity.onCreate(ModelsActivity.java:118)
```

And this is part of ModelsActivity.java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    .
    .
    .
    Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();       // line 117
    car = b.getParcelable("car");                  // line 118
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Thank u all

Comment: You should add something to check whether `b` is `null`. It looks as though your `getExtras()` call is returning `null`. It's not possible for memory allocation for a new object to fail silently and return `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most of NPEs are related to memeory issues. The reason of your exception is, android system destroys background activities if it needs memory. To prevent exceptions because of this reason, you should use `onSaveInstanceState` and `restoreInstanceState` methods which helps us to store data when android system destroys activities. It seems that your bundle becomes null after recreation of the activity.

You can simulate your exception by checking Developer options/ don't keep activities on your android device.